# What could be preventing context menus from showing up after installing TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I've installed the latest TortoiseSVN on my Windows 7 machine and the context sensitive menu doesn't show up even after a restart. How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Try reinstalling on top of the existing installation, and restarting your computer again. No guarantee this will work, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `64bit` windows you have to install `64bit` version of TortoiseSVN, is this the case with you?

**Update** Several reports confirm that installing twice (without uninstalling) or uninstal/install *twice* do fix the menu problem. Seems to be a TortoiseSVN bug.

Comment: still stuck with this issue, have gone through several rounds of install / uninstallation